# File scanning with fscanf

Tags: c

I have a problem with `fscanf`, which my structure array will keep both account number and name together in `customer[i].Acc_No`, and repeating keep my name in `customer[i].fullname`.
First time scanning won't have problem, it start from 2nd time. Why?

Example:

```
id:FAFB1234 name:LEE FU HUA

customer[0].Acc_No store "FABE1234LEE FU HUA"
```

My code:

```
information customers[10];
int i;
FILE *fptr;

fptr=fopen("Customer.txt","r");
file_check(fptr);

i=0;
while(!feof(fptr))
{
    fscanf(fptr,"%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%d %d %d %lf %d %d %d",customers[i].Acc_No,customers[i].fullname,customers[i].address
    ,&customers[i].birthday.day,&customers[i].birthday.month,&customers[i].birthday.year,&customers[i].balance_owning,&customers[i].last_trans.day
    ,&customers[i].last_trans.month,&customers[i].last_trans.year); 
i++
}
```

My txt file:

```
FAFB1234|LEE FU HUA|NO38 JALAN BUNGA TAMAN LAWA 48235 SHAH ALAM,SELANGOR|18 09 1995 0.00 1 9 2014
FEBE2014|LOW CHU TAO|A-111 JALAN YING TAMAN YANGYANG 56981 WANGSA MAJU,KUALA LUMPUR|30 03 1996 0.00 1 9 2014
FAFB2014|JERRY CHOW|I-414 JALAN MATINI TAMAN ASRAMA PENUH 56327 SETAPAK,KUALA LUMPUR|15 02 1995 0.00 1 9 2014
FEBE1001|LEE WEI KIET|NO 49 JALAN 5/6 TAMAN BUNGA SELATAN 48752 HULU SELANGOR,SELANGOR|06 09 1996 0.00 1 9 2014
FAFB1001|HO HUI QI|NO 888 JALAN 65/79 TAMAN TERLALU BESAR 75368 KUANTAN,PAHANG|26 04 1996 0.00 1 9 2014
```

Comment: I think english is not your first language, but please try to elaborate your problem a little more.

Comment: Also, consider providing  a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why do you have lots of spaces before the last `%d`?

Comment: Please provide the declaration of the type `information`.

Comment: Does `Acc_No` has enough space? and `while(!feof(fptr))` is wrong. and It is necessary to consider the newline.

Comment: 1) This fixes the main problem: Use `" %[^|]|% ..` (add space). 2) Use `" %8[^|]|% ..` (width 1 less than `sizeof Acc_No`  3) use `fgets()` as answered by @Sergey L.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` and family can have very unpredictable results reading directly from the stream. If a parse failed everything else is bound to fail afterwards.

When using `scanf` and family it's always recommended to read your data line by line with `fgets` and then `sscanf` on the buffer.

Try this:

```
information customers[10];
FILE *fptr;

fptr=fopen("Customer.txt","r");
file_check(fptr);


// buffer to read line by line
char line[0x1000];
int i = 0;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr)) {
    information this_customer; // buffer for surrent customer
    memset(&this_customer, 0, sizeof(this_customer));

    int num_entries_read = sscanf(line,"%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%d %d %d %lf %d %d %d",this_customer.Acc_No,this_customer.fullname,this_customer.address
        ,&this_customer.birthday.day,&this_customer.birthday.month,&this_customer.birthday.year,&this_customer.balance_owning,&this_customer.last_trans.day
        ,&this_customer.last_trans.month,&this_customer.last_trans.year);

    if (num_entries_read == 10) { // all fields were successfullt matched
        // copy this customer into the array
        customers[i] = this_customer;
        i++;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to parse line: %s", line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer.  Recommend `sscanf(line,"%[^|]` --> `sscanf(line,"%8[^|]`, etc.  But then OP did not post the information definition - sigh.